# What is a "pipe" file?

Tags: unix

My python script which uses multiprocessing is throwing an OSError because there are too many files.  I used the lsof command to list all of my files, and a lot of the entries look like

`python   3647  username   87r     FIFO     0,10      0t0 18562471 pipe`

Can you tell me how to interpret this?  What is a "pipe" file?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on the [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: You should read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285467/a-proposed-philosophy-of-question-migration?cb=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is, in UNIX, an old interprocess communication mechanism called a "named pipe" or a FIFO, for first-in/first-out. To your program it looks like a file, just as STDIN and STDOUT do. So it's exactly the named version of the intermediate buffer that you get with a pipe in the command line, for example

```
$ cat myfile.txt | wc -w
```

In UNIX, pretty near everything is addressed through the file system; named pipes are in the file system so they can be shared anong programs by name.